# How stop containers run with `docker-compose run`

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use `docker-compose` to orchestrate several containers. To troubleshoot, I frequently end up running bash from within a container by doing:

```
$ docker-compose run --rm run web bash
```

I always try pass the `--rm` switch so that these containers are removed when I exit the bash session. Sometimes though, they remain, and I see them at the output of `docker-compose ps`.

```
           Name                          Command                State      Ports
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
project_nginx_1            /usr/sbin/nginx                  Exit 0
project_nginx_run_1        bash                             Up         80/tcp
project_web_1              python manage.py runserver ...   Exit 128
project_web_run_1          bash                             Up         8000/tcp
```

At this point, I am trying to stop and remove these components manually, but I can not manage to do this. I tried:

```
$ docker-compose stop project_nginx_run_1
No such service: project_nginx_run_1
```

I also tried the other commands `rm`, `kill`, etc..

What should I do to get rid of these containers?

**Edit:**

Fixed the output of `docker-compose ps`.

Comment: Have you tried stopping via ID? `docker-compose stop b279062e8daa 41de31a0423c`?

Comment: Yes, I still get the `no service` error, this time with the container ID

Comment: I've noticed that my `docker-compose ps` output is significantly different - contains only 4 columns. Are you running `docker ps` by mistake?

Comment: You're right, I mistakenly pasted the output of `docker ps`. I fixed it now. I was running all commands with `docker-compose` though, so the question remains..

Answer (score 58, accepted):

just stop those test containers with the [`docker stop`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/stop/) command instead of using `docker-compose`.

`docker-compose` shines when it comes to start together many containers, but using `docker-compose` to start containers does not prevent you from using the `docker` command to do whatever you need to do with individual containers.

```
docker stop project_nginx_run_1 project_web_run_1
```

---

Also, since you are debugging containers, I suggest to use [`docker-compose exec <service id> bash`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/) to get a shell in a running container. This has the advantage of not starting a new container.

Comment: If you already have a few running containers invoked with run it might be useful to stop all running containers using  `docker stop $(docker ps -q)` before spinning your core containers back up.

Comment: Now you can do  `docker-compose stop project_nginx_run project_web_run` and then to remove `docker-compose rm -f  project_nginx_run project_web_run`

Comment: Simply issuing 

 `docker-compose stop`

in the directory containing the docker-compose.yaml file also works.

Comment: Additional note for when running detached: `docker-compose run -d` returns the container name on stdout, so capture it in a variable: `NAME=$(docker-compose run -d ...)`. Then use `docker rm -f $NAME`.

Comment: If the running containers have a `restart` policy, you might need first run `docker update --restart=no <containerName>` and then `docker stop ....`

Comment: @DanielW I have `restart=always` on all my compose services and I never had to update that to `no` in order for `docker stop` to work and my containers to stay stopped. (using docker 18.09.3 and docker-compose 1.23.1)

Answer (score 6):

With docker-compose, services can be stopped in two ways, but I would like add some detailed info about both options.

> ## In short
>
> ### `docker-compose down`
>
> Stop and remove containers, networks, images, and volumes
>
> ### `docker-compose stop`
>
> Stop services

---

## In detail

If `docker-compose run` starts services **project_nginx_run_1** and **project_web_run_1**, then

### `docker-compose down` log will be

```
$ docker-compose down
Stopping project_nginx_run_1 ...
Stopping project_web_run_1 ...

.
. some service logs goes here

Stopping project_web_run_1 ... done
Stopping project_nginx_run_1 ... done
Removing project_web_run_1 ... done
Removing project_nginx_run_1 ... done
Removing network project_default
```

### `docker-compose stop` log will be

```
$ docker-compose stop
Stopping project_nginx_run_1 ...
Stopping project_web_run_1 ...

.
. some service logs goes here

Stopping project_web_run_1 ... done
Stopping project_nginx_run_1 ... done
```

Comment: I don't know why that was downvoted but maybe the solution is too broad - I guess the original question is hoping to stop a single service.

Comment: The question asks how to stop containers started with docker-compose **run**, not docker-compose **up**. The `down` and `stop` commands don't work for containers started by **run**.

Answer (score 5):

The `docker-compose`, unlike `docker`, use the names for it's containers defined in the `yml` file. Therefore, to stop just one container the command will be:

```
docker-compose stop nginx_run
```

Comment: IMHO this is the only correct answer. I found that when using `restart: unless-stopped` on a container using docker-compose, if using `docker stop <service name>` then the service will simply restart, but only when using `docker-compose stop xxx` the service will really stop

Answer (score 0):

```
docker-compose down
```

from within the directory where it was launched, is the only way I managed to confirm it was stopped, as in `docker-compose ps` no longer yields it!

Comment: This would likely give unexpected results because the OPs goal was not to stop all running containers but just specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case,

```
docker compose down --remove-orphans
```

worked the best (but that is assuming that you don't need to continue running any of the services from a compose file)